# my wordpress keeps redirecting me to the original website

Tags: php, wordpress

i hope everyone is doing well !
my situation :
1- i have a production wordpress website in a virtual machine ,
2- i have cloned the vm and changed it's ip adresse and dns name ,
3- i changed the wp-config.php from :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://old-site-name.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://old-site-name.com');
```

to :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://new-site-name.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://new-site-name.com');
```

the problem :
when i type my new-site-name.com it redirect me to the old one
wordpress or php is not my area of experties could someone guide me to the right direction!!

Comment: Go to Settings -> General update your url. Check .htaccess for any additional redirection

Comment: you're talking about the web interface!

Comment: the problem is i can't access the new wordpress interface ! when i type the ip adress or hostname of the new one it redirect me to the original website ,and i can't change stuff from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in phpmyadmin select table wp_options and change
siteurl and home to http://new-site-name.com

Comment: works like a charm ! thank you